# SSIS TFS configuration

Tags: tfs, ssis, ssis-2012

I am trying to source control ssis packages

Installed TFS server component and created Team project collection.

There is no plug in to select in DATA TOOL->Option->Source control->Plugin

How to do this on SSIS 2012 !?

I have also installed explorer and expecting the visual studio level check in facility would appear in SSIS Data tools.

Comment: Sorry we have not got any thing installed on the environment.This is a charity organisation,so i have to do everything.we do not have dba or data architect.

Comment: your question is unclear. Are you trying to source control some SSIS packages or are you trying to use SSIS to interact with TFS?

Comment: I am trying to source control ssis packages

Comment: are you using the visual studio 2012 or visual studio 2013 version of SSDT-BI, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674919.aspx ?

Comment: and you said that you installed "explorer". are you saying that you installed Team Explorer after installing SSDT-BI? and are you sure you installed the correct Team Explorer version matching the Visual Studio version?

Comment: and what TFS version are you using, because I might need to point you to some service packs to get it to actually connect once you have the toolbar option available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have installed TFS 2012, and installed Team Explorer for VS 2012. after creating Team Project Collection, you also need to create a Team Project in Team Explorer.

To connect to TFS in SSDT, you can follow:

1. Launch SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT).
2. On the **Team** menu, click **Connect to Team Foundation Server**.
3. In the **Team Explorer** – **Connect** pane, click **Connect**.
4. In the **Connect to Team Foundation Server** dialog box, click **Servers**.
5. In the **Add/Remove Team Foundation Server** dialog box, click **Add**.
6. In the **Add Team Foundation Server** dialog box, enter the server information, click **OK**, and then click **Close** in the A**dd/Remove Team Foundation Server** dialog box.
7. In the **Connect to Team Project** dialog box, select the server you’ve added, click the appropriate team project, and then click **Connect**.