# Configuring TFS for SSIS packages

Tags: tfs, ssis, sql-server-2012

We are planning to do version control for our SSIS packages. I want to know how to install TFS and configure it to `checkin` SSIS packages.

I have read this [SSIS TFS configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35653562/ssis-tfs-configuration). But here I couldn't find anything about installation. it contains only connection information  TFS. Should I install from SSIS extensions? Should i install Team explorer?  It is showing so many options as shown below.I don't know the right one. Also is installing this requires any license? Please guide me here. Any link with the steps is also fine.

[image: Extension]

I'm using `Visual Studio 2015` and `SQL Server 2012`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know how to install TFS and configure it to checkin SSIS packages.

Refer to [Install and configure Team Foundation Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/backup/tut-single-svr-install-config-tfs?view=azure-devops) and [Integration Services (SSIS) and Visual Studio Team Foundation Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/dn463982(v=sql.110)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for details.

> Should I install from SSIS extensions? Should i install Team explorer?

Yes, to design the SSIS packages you need to download and install SSDT (SQL Server Data Tools). It's an official addon for Visual Studio which adds templates for SSIS and SSAS projects. Refer to [Download and install SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15) for details.

And you need to install the [Team Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/user-guide/work-team-explorer?view=azure-devops) to connect to TFS and manage the source control.

> is installing this requires any license?

It's based on your VS subscription, you can try community version of Visual Studio, it's free.

Besides, find following blogs for your reference, hope that helps.

- [SSIS 2012 with Team Foundation Server - Part I](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2014/03/ssis-2012-with-team-foundation-server.html)
- [SSIS 2012 with Team Foundation Server - Part II](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2014/03/ssis-2012-with-team-foundation-server_1.html)
- [Installing SSIS, SSRS and SSAS with Visual Studio 2019](https://tomaztsql.wordpress.com/2019/11/03/installing-ssis-ssrs-and-ssas-with-visual-studio-2019/)

Comment: Thanks for this. I will try this out :)

Comment: Done. But still have issues. I have installed VS 2015 shell (integrated). I couldn't find the Team( Team explorer) tab. Do you happen to know this?. I heard by default the Team tab will come

Comment: Sounds like a VS issue, Team Explorer exists as part of the Visual Studio 2015, that means it will be installed by default. Please refer to this thread to check if that helps : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cf3a1ab6-bb89-4a85-bc1d-e93bb96222f0/where-is-team-explorer-tab-in-visual-studio-2015?forum=visualstudiogeneral